# What are the Git conflict markers syntax/rules?

Tags: regex, git, perl, merge-conflict-resolution

I am interested in what the rules are for the Git conflict markers? Are they stacked? What are the rules to opening (<<<<<<<) and closing (>>>>>>>)? I tried searching the Git docs, but there is nothing explicit about these and the only examples I find are simple, single, non-stacked conflicts.

Context:
I need to sync two independent branches that have the same directory structure partially. I am creating a patch from one and applying it to the other branch. Conflicts are possible, but I always want to take 'ours'.

For applying the patch I use:
`git apply --3way --ignore-whitespace --whitespace=fix <patchfile>`

Then for each file that contains conflict markers I do this:
`perl -i -0777 -pe '<{7} ours\r?\n((?:(?!<{7})(?!={7})(?!>{7}).*\r?\n)*?)={7}\r?\n(?:(?!<{7})(?!={7})(?!>{7}).*\r?\n)*?>{7} theirs\r?\n'`

Basically I assume that the markers are stacked (from what I noticed) and try to solve them from inside out (innermost to outermost). This is how the file is after applying the patch:

```
<<<<<<< ours
<<<<<<< ours
<<<<<<< ours
{chunk of text}
<<<<<<< ours
=======
{chunk of text}
>>>>>>> theirs
=======
{chunk of text}
>>>>>>> theirs
{chunk of text}
<<<<<<< ours
=======
=======
>>>>>>> theirs
{chunk of text}
<<<<<<< ours
>>>>>>> theirs
=======
>>>>>>> theirs
=======
>>>>>>> theirs

{rest of file}
```

The problem is that now I found a file that after 2 substitution iterations reaches this state:

```
<<<<<<< ours
<<<<<<< ours
{text chunk}
<<<<<<< ours
=======
=======
>>>>>>> theirs
{text chunk}
<<<<<<< ours
>>>>>>> theirs
=======
>>>>>>> theirs
=======
>>>>>>> theirs

<rest of file>
```

... and I don't know what to make of this. This doesn't seem stacked. How should I resolve these conflicts?

Note: I also ran the regex manually iteration by iteration in an online debugger and it matches ok.

**Edit for clarifications:** When I wrote this I failed to mention that I am using git format-patch to generate the patch and this actually generates a patch for each commit in order to keep metadata, hence the multiple conflict markers.
@torek nailed it in his answer without having the proper information.

Comment: Are they stacked? Or are you comparing a file that contains them already?

Comment: This may be helpful: [Git merge conflicts](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-conflicts)

Comment: You shouldn't have _stacked_ conflicts..... even recursive strategy produces non-stacked conflicts... and they should be removed by the time you commit. Anyway, what I wanted to say is that git can be told to take _ours_ on conflicting pieces of code, no need to write that by hand.

Comment: @ikegami I checked both branches manually and they don't already contain conflict markers. These are added by git apply

Comment: @eftshift0 How do you do that with git apply? I see that git merge has a flag for conflict resolution, but not git apply.
Also, what do you base your assertion on? ("You shouldn't have stacked conflicts")
I actually did find stacked conflicts on all files while working on this up until this file.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Not really. It is the classic example of a simple conflict.

Comment: @RaduC Right, I thought it explained nested things too. Oh, well, worth a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conflict markers do not stack.

When Git is doing a file-level merge, there are three input files.<sup>1</sup>  Git calls the second file "ours" and the third one "theirs", and does not really have a proper name for the first one.  The first one, however, is from the *merge base*.  When you run `git merge`, Git works on a *commit* basis, and the three files for each case are from three *commits* that Git calls the merge base, the "ours" commit, and the "theirs" commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>When you use `git merge`, these rules are specific to particular *merge strategies*, but the ones you'll use, that produce conflict markers in work-tree files, follow these rules.  When you use `git apply --3way` and it has to do a true merge, it invokes this same code.

---

But you're using `git apply`, which constructs each step one file at a time:

- The "ours" file is the one in your work-tree, or in your index, depending on what flags you give to `git apply`.  I will assume here that you are using the work-tree file (when using the index copy, enough other things are different that it's pretty clear that you are not using the index copy).
- The "theirs" file isn't directly visible: in fact, it doesn't exist yet.
- The "base" file may not exist either.  If it doesn't exist, and the patch doesn't apply well, we won't even get to this point.  If it *does* exist, it's been supplied by the `index` line in the patch, which contains a raw hash ID.

So, at this point, since the patch *is* being applied *and* Git is doing a three-way merge on the file, Git *did* find the merge base file.  Because the patch text was derived *from* this base file, the patch applies easily *to* the base file, which produces the "theirs" file.  Git's job is now to merge *their changes* (i.e., the patch) with *our changes* (the base file vs ours).

Git now makes a second diff, from the base file to our file, to see what we changed.  If we added a line after line 42 before line 43, and they didn't touch the lines around lines 42–43, Git can take our extra line.  If they changed line 50, Git can change line 50 of the base file (which is line 51 of our file since we added a line).  This kind of combining goes on wherever we and they touched *different lines* in the file.

Where we and they touched *the same* line, though, or touched lines that abut (e.g., if we changed line 55 and they changed line 56), Git declares a *merge conflict*.  It writes, to the work-tree file:

```
<<<<<<< ours
our version
=======
their version
>>>>>>> theirs
```

and then continues on with the unchanged lines.  If we set `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3`, Git includes the *base* version of the lines, between these two versions, marked off by seven `|` characters.

#### This work-tree file is your new work-tree file

You are now going ahead and running a *second* `git apply` that needs to do a three-way merge.  Your second `git apply` takes the work-tree file as is, and *assumes that this is what we think the file should look like*.  (It's not, of course!  But Git assumes it is.)

So, Git now finds the merge base version of the file, and runs a `git diff` to see what *we* changed.  Apparently, what *we* changed was to insert these huge `<<<<<<< ours`, `=======`, and `>>>>>>> theirs` markers along with both our and their changes.

Meanwhile, Git compares the base version of the file against their version of the file—that's the patch you're applying—and now Git tries to combine our changes with their changes.  *Sometimes*, you'll get:

```
<<<<<<< ours
[the entire block from the first `git apply`]
=======
[theirs]
>>>>>>> theirs
```

which *will* nest properly, but *sometimes*, the ours or their changes will "line up": the two diffs will synchronize and Git will, in effect, say: *aha, our version of the file is the same as theirs here*.  So we'll get:

```
<<<<<<< ours
[part of the block from ours]
=======
[part of the diff from theirs]
>>>>>>> theirs
the synchronized part
<<<<<<< ours
=======
...
```

where the second `<<<<<<< ours` is from when the diffs "lost sync" again and hit the `=======` in our file—unless, that is, we get very (bad-)lucky and the `=======` actually is part of the synchronization.

#### What to do about this

After running `git apply`, *do not go on to apply more patches*.  Resolve the problem first.

Optionally, consider using `git merge-file` so that you can change the conflict markers.

Comment: Not sure how `git merge-file` helps here.  You can change the labels, and you can change the size of the markers, but you can't change the markers themselves.  The best answer is definitely: "stop, fix the conflicts, ensure they've all been resolved, then move to the next patch.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister: with the different labels-and-size you can tell where the earlier markers were, but yes, I agree that this is the wrong way to go. It's just another option.

Comment: Thanks for this! I realized yesterday what was happening, but forgot to check stackoverflow. I was going to provide the solution that I found or rather the problem that was causing this.
I failed to mention that I was using format-patch instead of diff for generating the patch and this was generating a file with all the commits, causing multiple conflicts. I ended up using simple diff because I did not need individual commit metadata.